# Precisely how does Pytest logging work?

Tags: logging, pytest

I've read the various questions about pytest-catchlog etc but I'm none the wiser - how exactly does Pytest do logging?

I have a top-level Python app that creates a log file. There are a number of modules used by the app and their logging also ends up in the log file.  But I want to unit test these modules and when I write a Pytest unit test and run it, there is no logging anywhere from the modules.

I've seen talk about 'pytest-catchlog' but it talks about stdout and the like and I don't even see my logs appearing on screen.  So how *is* Pytest generating (or not) logs and how can I tap in and get the log file that I want?

Comment: have you tried the options `-vv` and `-s` to increase the verbosity and capture logs. [pytest-capture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/3.1.0/capture.html)

Comment: Thanks - what has been confusing me was that '-s' is about stdout and I've only ever seen logging to files.  However having now figured out that logging can also be a glorified print(), I've managed to see what is happening.  It seems that whoever wrote the product that I've inherited wrote their own logging code in a very odd manner and apparently that's been totally sabotaging my attempts to use logging.  So a combination of improving this strange code and your -s/-vv suggestions  is starting to yield results.  Thanks.